# Load input table not honoring secure_file_priv

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I ran `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv"` and I got this result:
'secure_file_priv', 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\'

I loaded the csv file to the Uploads directory and ran this command:
`load data infile 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Household.csv' replace into table bb.household
fields ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'`
;
I got the following :
Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement.

What am I missing?  I even tried "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Household.csv" as the file path and I still got the error code above.

What am I missing?  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

MG

Comment: Your variable specifies ...\MySQL Server 8.0\ **Uploads** \, while your filename is in the parent directory (without `\uploads`).

Comment: Apologies for typo in original post.  I did try it with 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\Household.csv' .  Is there special syntax for filenames with spaces in them?

Comment: No, spaces are fine, but \ should be either escaped with two `\\ ` or you should use `/` instead (`C:/ProgramData/My...`).

Comment: Tried the \\ just now and got the same message...I'm doing this in workbench.  Could that be the problem?